# nginx returning 404 for valid request path

Tags: nginx

I set out to deploy letsencrypt on my server but quickly failed with a really frustrating error. I set up a webroot and tested it with a sample `hello.txt` file:

```
~]# cat /tmp/letsencrypt-auto/well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt
hello
~]# ls -lZ /tmp/letsencrypt-auto/well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt
-rw-rw-r--. martin martin unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/letsencrypt-auto/well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt
~]# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
<truncated>
    location /well-known/acme-challenge {
        default_type  "text/plain";
        root          /tmp/letsencrypt-auto;
    }
<truncated>
```

However, requesting the `hello.txt` file by browsing to `http://example.com/well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt` returns a 404 and this error in the log file:

```
2015/12/14 10:39:42 [error] 5898#5898: *232 open() "/tmp/letsencrypt-auto/well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXX, server: XXX, request: "GET /well-known/acme-challenge/hello.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "XXX"
```

The `site.conf` file of course contains other directives but even if I comment them all out leaving only the `/well-known...` rule, it still returns a 404. Any ideas what could be causing this? The file clearly exists, yet it feels like nginx can't see it. Turning off SELinux does not help either, btw.

Comment: Can you `cat` the file as the user that runs `nginx`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I can. I log in with `su -s /bin/bash - nginx`, and can see the contents of the file just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some weirdness in serving from `/tmp/`. When I moved it to my site's location under `/srv/` everything worked fine.